# Form of the restoring force in a string which carries a wave

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, waves, potential-energy, conservative-field

A string is stretched when a wave is traveling over it. We also calculate the potential energy in the string due to the restoring forces,which arise due to the fact that the string is stretched.

Since the potential is defined only for conservative forces, I was wondering what model do we have for these internal string forces, which are conservative.

I couldn't find this discussion in my text book .

I'd be glad if someone pointed anything relevant. Thank you

Comment: I don't understand the question. The potential is $U = \frac{1}{2}k x^2,$ and the (restoring) force is $-\partial U/\partial x = -kx.$

Comment: How do we know the energy is1/2Kx^2 ?